# I am not able to view message in messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I got a notification from stackoverflow that i have received a message from a company, where I recently apply for the job and he asked some questions but i am not able to view the message on website for reply, below is the url of message I received on email:
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages/1306669

Kindly, let me know what is wrong

Comment: That URL format is working for me, though it does redirect to something like this `http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages?userId=XXXXXXXX/#!/inbox/YYYYYYYY`

Comment: Yes, it redirects properly but does not show me the messages and keeps loading forever

Comment: Can you see the message in your inbox when you visit the website?

Comment: When i navigate through notification link, then i keeps loading, see screenshot: http://imageshack.com/a/img922/5107/2NYq5A.png
And when i navigate to messages from website it shows me "no messages to show" message: http://imageshack.com/a/img922/410/Q0r8ps.png

Comment: @kami998 Are you getting any errors in the developer console (press F12)? Also, are you using any browser extensions?

Comment: I have tried it over multiple devices and browsers, so i can say that its not related to any browser extensions or specific browser issue, but in console there is an error in loading a javascript file http://10.80.196.101:8080/www/default/base.js (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT), or may be the message has been deleted by the sender and it does not exists in system any more...

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. A fix is going out shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix has been deployed. There was a bug in the SQL that pulled all of a user's viewable threads out of the db. Thanks for the report!

Comment: I spotted something weird in the [revisions on the MSE stub](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/276861/revisions) - did you put [meta-tag:status-reproduced] by mistake in there, then removed it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, just jumped the gun before realizing it was the stub.

Comment: feature request: show a warning for users with diamond when they try to edit locked posts. :-)

Comment: @G-Wiz Thanks, its resolved now

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue now in 2018, but as you can see from developer console error message tells you what the problem is and where. So I deactivated AdBlocker and issue were solved :)[image]